# Database Request By Location - Advice?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I need advice on how to query a database for specific information based off a variable entered by the user.

Each document in my database has a location (lat, lng). 
Users enter their location in a search bar which converts the location to (lat, lng). 
The website displays all the locations within 100 miles of the users location.

Here is my question:

Do I request ALL the documents in the database and filter them on the front end? There are a lot of documents...

or

Do I send the users entered location to my server and request certain ones?

Thanks for the advice and help!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB supports geo indexes and geo queries.